# Why can't my CSV File display the content onto my graph?

Tags: java, swing, csv

Well basically what my program does is that I have a csv file that reads in the
milliseconds (which I converted) and a letter that represents a zone. I am trying to display it as a bar chart but I have different tabs that each letter (zone) goes to. My
issue is trying to send the letter (from file) to the specific zone which I made in tabs. Maybe I am missing something but I am not sure. Any help will be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "serial", "deprecation" })
public class InductionTreeGraph extends JFrame {

static TimeSeries ts = new TimeSeries("data", Millisecond.class);

public static void add(JTabbedPane jtp, String label, int mnemonic, AbstractButton button1)
{
    int count = jtp.getTabCount();
    JButton button = new JButton(label);
    button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    jtp.addTab(label, null, button, null);
    jtp.setMnemonicAt(count, mnemonic);

}

public InductionTreeGraph() throws Exception {

        final XYDataset dataset = (XYDataset) createDataset();
        final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 400));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Induction Zone Chart");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
        jtp.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
        String zones[] = {"Zone A", "Zone B", "Zone C", "Zone S",
                "Zone SH","Zone W"};
        int mnemonic[] = {KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.VK_B, KeyEvent.VK_C,
                KeyEvent.VK_S, KeyEvent.VK_H,KeyEvent.VK_W};

        for (int i = 0, n=zones.length; i<n; i++)
        {
            AbstractButton button1 = null;
            InductionTreeGraph.add(jtp, zones[i], mnemonic[i], button1);
        }

        final JPanel p = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Update") {

             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                chartPanel.repaint();
             }

        }));

        frame.add(jtp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(chartPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private XYDataset createDataset() {
        final TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(ts);

        TreeMap<String,TreeMap<Integer,Integer[]>> zoneMap = getInductions("","");
        // Iterate through all zones and print induction rates for every minute into
        // every hour by zone...
        Iterator<String> zoneIT = zoneMap.keySet().iterator();
        while (zoneIT.hasNext())
        {
            String zone = zoneIT.next();
            TreeMap<Integer,Integer[]> hourCountsInZoneMap = zoneMap.get(zone);
            System.out.println("ZONE " + zone + " : ");
            Iterator<Integer> hrIT = hourCountsInZoneMap.keySet().iterator();
            while (hrIT.hasNext())
            {
                int hour = hrIT.next();
                Integer [] indRatePerMinArray = hourCountsInZoneMap.get(hour);
                for (int i=0; i< indRatePerMinArray.length; i++)
                {
                    System.out.print(hour + ":");
                    System.out.print(i < 10 ? "0" + i : i);
                    System.out.println(" = " + indRatePerMinArray[i] + " induction(s)");
                }
            }
        }

        return dataset;
}

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset) {
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYBarChart(
                "Induction Zone Chart", 
                "Hour", 
                true,
                "Inductions Per Minute", 
                (IntervalXYDataset) dataset, 
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                false, 
                true, 
                false
        );

        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot)chart.getPlot();
        XYBarRenderer renderer = (XYBarRenderer)plot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setBarPainter(new StandardXYBarPainter());
        renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);
        ValueAxis axis = plot.getDomainAxis();
            axis.setAutoRange(true);
            axis.setFixedAutoRange(60000.0);

        // Set an Induction target of 30 per minute
        Marker target = new ValueMarker(30);
        target.setPaint(java.awt.Color.blue);
        target.setLabel("Induction Rate Target");
        plot.addRangeMarker(target);

        return chart;
    }

private TreeMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, Integer[]>> getInductions(String mills, String zone) {

    // TreeMap of Inductions for Every Minute in Day Per Zone...
    // Key = Zone
    // Value = TreeMap of Inductions per Minute per Hour:
    //          Key = Hour
    //          Value = Array of 60 representing Induction Rate Per Minute
    //                  (each element is the induction rate for that minute)
    TreeMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, Integer[]>> zoneMap = new TreeMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, Integer[]>>();

    // Input file name...
    String fileName = "/home/a002384/ECLIPSE/IN070914.CSV";

    try 
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line;
        try
        {
            // Read a line from the csv file until it reaches to the end of the file...
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // Parse a line of text in the CSV...
                String [] indData = line.split("\\,");
                long millisecond = Long.parseLong(indData[0]);
                String zone1 = indData[1];

                // The millisecond value is the number of milliseconds since midnight.
                // From this, we can derive the hour and minute of the day as follows:
                int secOfDay = (int)(millisecond / 1000);
                int hrOfDay = secOfDay / 3600;
                int minInHr = secOfDay % 3600 / 60;

                // Obtain the induction rate TreeMap for the current zone.
                // If this is a "newly-encountered" zone, create a new TreeMap.
                TreeMap<Integer, Integer[]> hourCountsInZoneMap;
                if (zoneMap.containsKey(zone1))
                    hourCountsInZoneMap = zoneMap.get(zone1);
                else
                    hourCountsInZoneMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer[]>();

                // Obtain the induction rate array for the current hour in the current zone.
                // If this is a new hour in the current zone, create a new array,
                // and initialize this array with all zeroes.
                // The array is size 60, because there are 60 minutes in the hour.
                // Each element in the array represents the induction rate for that minute.
                Integer [] indRatePerMinArray;
                if (hourCountsInZoneMap.containsKey(hrOfDay))
                    indRatePerMinArray = hourCountsInZoneMap.get(hrOfDay);
                else
                {
                    indRatePerMinArray = new Integer[60];
                    Arrays.fill(indRatePerMinArray, 0);
                }

                // Increment the induction rate for the current minute by one.
                // Each line in the csv file represents a single induction at a
                // single point in time.
                indRatePerMinArray[minInHr]++;

                // Add everything back into the TreeMaps if these are newly-created.
                if (!hourCountsInZoneMap.containsKey(hrOfDay))
                    hourCountsInZoneMap.put(hrOfDay, indRatePerMinArray);
                if (!zoneMap.containsKey(zone1))
                    zoneMap.put(zone1, hourCountsInZoneMap);

            }
        }
        finally
        {
            br.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return zoneMap;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        InductionTreeGraph dem = new InductionTreeGraph();
        dem.pack();
        dem.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        while(true) {
            double millisecond = 2;
            double num = millisecond;
            System.out.println(num);
            ts.addOrUpdate(new Millisecond(), num);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My very first suggestion is about this line:

```
setContentPane(chartPanel);
```

Don't mess with content pane. Use this line instead:

```
getContentPane().add(chartPanel);
```

---

The prooblem I see in your code is that `InductionTreeGraph` extends from `JFrame` and you are setting this `chartPanel` as this frame's content pane, but then you use a new `JFrame` local variable (called `frame`) and add this `chartPanel` to this frame as well:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Induction Zone Chart");
...
frame.getContentPane().add(chartPanel);
```

Swing components are intended to be used "as is" so it's preferable composition over inheritance. Having said this you should consider remove `extends JFrame` on your class declaration and add all your components (chart panel, buttons, etc) to this local `frame` instead.

---

#### Related

You may want to take a look to the example shown in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20154153/1795530). This or any @trashgod's examples in Stack Overflow about `JFreeChart` (f.e. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24762078/1795530)) might help you to better structure your code.

Comment: +1 @user3841414 See [Extends JFrame vs. creating it inside the the program](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22003802/2587435)